# VB.Net DataColumn requires valid data type

Tags: vb.net, image, types, bitmap

I have a simple data table, and I require one column to contain the contents of an image so that I can bind it to a picture box for use in a data repeater. My following code returns the error that `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is not a valid data type, but I cannot find one that is.

```
Dim ListData As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim FirstImageColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
FirstImageColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Bitmap")
FirstImageColumn.ColumnName = "FirstImage"
ListData.Columns.Add(FirstImageColumn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it is an old post. This answer works for me.

```
 Dim fileImg As Image = fileIcon.ToBitmap
 column = New DataColumn("Image", GetType(Bitmap))
                    DocumentsDT.Columns.Add(column)
 dr("Image") = fileImg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the property DataType of a DataColumn to types that are not recognized by the object.

In the MSDN for the [property DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) you could read

> The DataType property supports the following base .NET Framework data types:
>   Boolean, Byte, Char, DateTime, Decimal, Double, Guid, Int16,
>   Int32, Int64, SByte, Single, String, TimeSpan, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64,
>   Byte[]

To store an Image in a DataTable you need to define its DataType property to `byte[]`, then you can easily found the code to store an image in a column of that type

For example (not tested)

```
Dim ListData As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim FirstImageColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
FirstImageColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]")
FirstImageColumn.ColumnName = "FirstImage"
ListData.Columns.Add(FirstImageColumn)
Dim img = Image.FromFile("....path to image file...")
Dim row = ListData.NewRow()
Dim ms = new MemoryStream()
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
row["FirstImage"] = ms.ToArray()
ListData.Rows.Add(row)
```